# How can I change memory limit of my site

Tags: magento-1.9

I get error like memory not enough,

[image]

but I have changed memory limit in code part,

[image]

After I went to check my site, memory limit was not changed, and Product Attributes Index not successes.

My php info,

[image]

Comment: Verify, in the phpinfo() if the php.ini file you modified is being used (GENERAL section)

Comment: why my menu collapsed,

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZIJfVAY.png

Answer (score 2):

you get increase memory limit from .htaccess by adding `php_value memory_limit  1024M` to `<IfModule mod_php5.c>`.

```
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_value memory_limit  1024M
    </IfModule>
```

You can also increase memory by putting a `php.ini` file in magento root.

```
    memory_limit = 64M
```

Comment: If i export products using the path System->import/export->export, its return "No Valid Data Send" Report. May i know why i am getting  this error? Is any memory issue? If i export single products using enter single sku the products export working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to restart the Webserver (looks like Apache to me) to make this change happen.
Alternatively, in some hosting environments you can use the `.htaccess` file in the Magento root directory to change the memory limit:

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

Comment: already did what you told,

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Nh5FPre.png

Comment: But i can't reindex my product attributes

Comment: Maybe you are not allowed to change these values. You should contact your hoster

Comment: Wimpy shared server contracts don't let you change these kind of settings. Get an ecommerce friendly hosting plan that allows you to increase memory_limit through the cPanel

Answer (score 1):

You can change the memory limit globally in php.ini, look for this line:

**memory_limit =**

and adjust the value acording to your needs,

also you can do it in index.php using below code:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
```

Comment: memory limit = ini_set("memory_limit","512M");

Comment: is it right .....

Comment: just only you need to put `ini_set("memory_limit","512M");`

Comment: menu collapsed  http://i.imgur.com/ZIJfVAY.png

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that there are two separate memory limits in PHP config files - one for the Apache and second for the Command Line (CLI).

Usual apache php.ini configuration file location:
`/etc/php5/apache/php.ini`

Usual command line configuration file location:
`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

If your script is run from shell or is planned as cron task the CLI configuration will be used.

Some servers allow `php.ini` file inside vhost root for specific vhost configuration. You can try create one and add following line inside it:

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 128M
```

If you're going to use `ini_set("memory_limit","512M");` always remember to set it back to it's original value after the code that requires bigger amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Most of you will be using WHM. MultiPHP INI Editor to edit the memory limit restriction and check back in phpinfo.php

Comment: If i export products using the path System->import/export->export, its return "No Valid Data Send" error. May i know why i am getting  this error? Is any memory issue? If i export single products using enter single sku the products export working.